# How to Prevent Duplicates with Generated Values on Batch Inserts

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, unique

My group class has a token attribute that my Java code uses to validate if an operation should be permitted depending on who is trying to invoke it. I have code that I am using to generate an alphanumeric key and assigning the token within the group constructor. e.g.

```
public Group(){
    super();
    this.token = Crypt.generate(30); // length of key
}
```

This is working fine and my database is small right now, however, I am thinking that there is a chance that the key generated will already exist. In this case when I try to insert the data into the database I'll receive a org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException. I debated wrapping every insert statement in a try/catch and then trying again, but I would also need to check for the records that could have been successfully saved because I am usually inserting into the Group table in a batch process at the moment.

```
List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
groups.add(new Group("grp1");
groups.add(new Group("grp2");
groups.add(new Group("grp3");

try {
   groupRepository.save(groups);

} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){

   List<Group> secondAttemptGroups = new ArrayList<>();

   for(Group g : groups){

       Group insertedGroup = groupRepository.findByName(g.getName());

       if(insertedGroup == null){

           secondAttempGroups.add(new Group(g.getName());   
       }
   }
   if(!(secondAttempGroups.isEmpty()){

      try {

          group.repository.save(secondAttempGroups);

      } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e2){
          // ...
      }
   }
}
```

There must be a better way to protect against this.

Comment: What is this token. Is it just a random unique key? If so, use a UUID.

Comment: Or let the database create the keys for you.

Comment: What is a UUID?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking more about the problem I thought that I might be able to validate the tokens with Spring JPA without bringing the entire database into my code. This is what I came up with.

```
public static List<Group> validateTokens(List<Group> groups, int iterations){

    LOGGER.info("Validating Tokens: Iteration #" + iterations); 

    boolean dirtyToken = false;

    // Validate that the groups provided don't contain duplicate tokens. 

    Set<String> tokenSet = new HashSet<>();

    for(Group g1 : groups){
        tokenSet.add(g1.getToken());
    }
    if(tokenSet.size() != groups.size()){
        dirtyToken = true;

        for(Group g2 : groups){
            g2.setToken(Crypt.generate(TOKEN_LENGTH));
        }
    }

    // Validate that the groups provided don't contain tokens that are already present in the database.

    for(Group g3 : groups){
        Group databaseGroup = groupRepository.findByToken(g3.getToken());

        if(databaseGroup != null){
            dirtyToken = true;
            g3.setToken(Crypt.generate(TOKEN_LENGTH));
        }
    }
    if(dirtyToken && iterations-- > 0){
        return validateTokens(groups, iterations);
    }
    else if(dirtyToken && iterations < 1){
        LOGGER.warn("Tokens could not be validated and Unique Constraint Violtation will be thrown. " + 
                    "Perhaps it's time to increase the token length from " + TOKEN_LENGTH + ".");
        return groups;
    }
    else {
        return groups;
    }
```

The recursive method above works. @Robert I didn't consider a database generated value, but during development I will be using h2 only as my database. Would that approach still be feasible and perhaps easier?